# Asp.net V5 Web API fails to add reference to AspNet.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I have created a new Web Api project in VS2015 community Edition using framework 4.6

This new project has no extra references other than the ones that were added by default. When I attempt to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` I get the following error
[image]

Strangely enough, I have another Web Api project in the same solution to which I have added the same reference and it works. I can't seem to figure out what is going on here. Please help.

Comment: See "Errors - see Error List" next to your references? What errors do you see here? It's likely due to package version you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

just try install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Framework via NuGet Manager.

Comment: Thanks. Thats the first thing I tried before putting up this post. Does not work that way too. The way I fixed this particular problem is by using `dnu restore` However, my project still fails to build. I can't figure out why. I am getting errors like `System.Array` not defined or `System.Int32` not defined, which is weird. Those should come out of the basic references already added in..right?